# How to print list of categories and click on each category one by one in selenium/appium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium

[image]

I want to print and then click on list of all items like home top stories, latest news, opinion etc each and every category as you can see in image but did get success please help..

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.id("com.readwhere.whitelabel.prabhatkhabar:id/left_drawer_list"));        

 for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)       
 {
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getText()+"\n");
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What is your code output? Any errors? Can you please specify what exactly happening when you run your code?

Comment: @Siva27 i am not getting any error , please check the appium logs for the image attached

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are trying to find the list with wrong id. If in this window only category names are present as text, try find with texts.

After trying findElements with valid id, you need to click each category and then return to window containing the list again. Try this way:

```
// Trying to find the list with texts
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getText() + "\n");
    list.get(i).click(); // clicking on each category
    // navigate back to previous window
}
```

For navigating back, you can use this code:

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with the below code:

```
 List<WebElement> listForSize =driver.findElements(By.id("com.readwhere.whitelabel.prabhatkhabar:id/left_drawer_list"));        

    int size = listForSize.size();

    for (int i=0; i< size;i++)       
    { 
        //this is taken again because you are navigate back again
        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id("com.readwhere.whitelabel.prabhatkhabar:id/left_drawer_list"));
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText() + "\n");
        list.get(i).click();
        driver.navigate().back();
        Thread.sleep(2000);//avoid this kind of waiting. wait using until

    }
```

let me know if any error occurs.

Comment: it is not showing any error it just clicks on 6 category opinion and then stops.

Comment: only in sixth or one to six and than stops??

Comment: it clicks only 6th category and then stops

Comment: have you checked what is the size of the list? pls let me know the list size. just print this System.out.println(listForSize.size());

Comment: if i used List<WebElement> listForSize =driver.findElements(By.id("com.readwhere.whitelabel.prabhatkhabar:id/left_drawer_list"));        
it shows size of list  1 

if i write 
List<WebElement> list =driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));  

it shows 19 size of list and prints home top stories  and some categories but some other random text as well..

Comment: i tried this driver.findElements(By.id("com.readwhere.whitelabel.prabhatkhabar:id/menuTextView")); 

and it worked to some extent it printed home top stories and latest news and click on them as well but i faced problem in 4th category as it has sub category .

2ndly  it shows size 11 (as it is only storing those elements that are visible on 1st screen it is not storing elements from 12th category as they are from 2nd screen(in dropdown)

Comment: i think if you can take the list path properly, it will work. you can try by using By.className("android.widget.TextView").

Comment: is there any other alternative where i can store all the elements in list

Comment: actually its working only problem is it is only storing element that are present in that screen , but i want to store all the elements thats present in dropdown.

Comment: if an element which is not visible to screen, but you want to click , u have to scroll down to that element or swipe the screen. if you know how to do this , apply it but if not, than there's a lot of suggestion how to scroll or swipe using appium .  link    http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/11/appium-how-to-swipe-vertical-and.html  use it properly while dropdown comes.

Comment: is my answer help you?

Comment: yes and i am able to lot more , could you help me with this one 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330373/how-to-go-to-next-screen-of-an-app-using-appium