# How to go to next screen of an app using appium?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium

Can anyone tell me how to go to next screen, for example like in Times of India or Indian Express app or news in shorts app, there are 50 news stories and I want to go on all the pages so how to swipe till 50th page?

I tried `driver.swipe(344, 955, 346,247, 3000)`; with that I am able to swipe to next pages, but I am not sure how go to all the 50 pages one by one.

Comment: @saurabh i tried driver.swipe(344, 955, 346,247, 3000);

with that i am able to swipe to next pages , but not sure how go to all the 50 pages one by one.

Comment: I have edited your answer to include the extra information you put in your comment. Remember, on this site everybody is encouraged to [edit] their questions to improve them as much as possible.

Comment: What, if anything goes wrong with your driver.swipe call? What is stopping you doing that for all 50 pages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a for loop?

```
int pageCount = 50;
for(int currentPage = 1; currentPage < pageCount; currentPage++){
    driver.swipe(344, 955, 346,247, 3000);
    Thread.sleep(1000);//If you want to wait 1 second between pages
    //Or do whatever you want on each page.
}
```